# Write and Analytical expression and compute H(X) for $2^{-i}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, entropy

X is a random variable over the positive integers {1,2,3...} such that for each positive integer i,

Pr[X = i] = $2^{-i}$

Write an Analytical expression and compute H(X)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$H(X)=-\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}p_i\log_2 p_i=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{i}{2^i}=\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{2}}{(1-\dfrac{1}{2})^2}=2\ \ bits$$This makes sence and there exist an optimal coding scheme as following:

> we code $X=1$ with binary sequence $0$
>
> we code $X=2$ with binary sequence $10$
>
> we code $X=3$ with binary sequence $110$
>
> we code $X=4$ with binary sequence $1110$
>
> we code $X=5$ with binary sequence $11110$
>
> we code $X=6$ with binary sequence $111110$
>
> and so on

this code is also an instantaneous code and as you can see the average length of the former binary code sequences is exactly as much as $H(X)$ (That's why this code is referred to as optimal).

Comment: I don't really understand how pi log2 pi reduced to i / 2^i. Can your explain a bit ? So you have the entropy formula listed so is the express i posted the new entropy formula ? and that's why it's the case?

Comment: Sure! Just substitute $p_i$ with $\dfrac{1}{2^i}$ in the main equation of entropy